# Making a DIV stay in the upper right corner against the browser window. It should stay there and never move even when the window is re-sized?

Tags: jquery, css

This is the code:

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container{
    background-color: #060;
    width: 1006px;
    margin: 0 auto;;
    height: 700px; /*HEIGHT GIVEN FOR DEMOSTRATION PERPOSES ONLY.*/
}

#mainContent{
    background-color: #CCC;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;;
    height: 400px; /*HEIGHT GIVEN FOR DEMOSTRATION PERPOSES ONLY.*/
}

#ad{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #F90;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="ad">
    </div>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="mainContent">
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

I am trying to placed a div containing an ad on the top of a page. I need this div to be in the top right corner against the walls of the browser right and top window.

I have managed to do this by making the DIV absolute positioned, give it a 0px Right and top placement. So it sits there perfectly.

Here is the problem:

When you minimized the browser window, the div scrolls with the page and have a big space behind it, depending how small you make the window.

To work around this, I change the DIV's width to 100 percent and place the ad image in the background positioned top right. I am thinking because the DIV is 100 percent and hit's the walls of the window, it will shrink and grow according to the window size and the image will stay put in the right corner. Not happening.

Does anyone have an idea about how I can make this DIV stay in the upper right corner against the browser window. It should stay there and never move even when the window is re-sized?

Comment: Does your website have a fixed width, such as `960px`? Is there any chance you could make a [jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net) of your HTML/CSS showing the problem?

Comment: Could you provide a link to an example please?

Comment: Let me post a quick example: In the main time the page has a fixed width which is the container. However because I want this to float over the entire page including the container, I placed the div right after the body rather then in a container.

Comment: Here is a quick code I whipped: This is the exact code:

Comment: I am having trouble adding the code, how do I paste the code in here?

Answer (score 5):

use fixed positioning:

```
position : fixed;
top      : 0px;
right    : 0px;
```

Comment: Hi cwolves, Well I need the ad to sit on top of the page, using fixed will not make it do that, it has to be absolute positioned . I also tried making the ad image which is in the background of the div fixed but that causes  the image to disappears in the div since the DIV is also scrolling.

Comment: @Overmars Move the div so that its parent is the page body.

Comment: fudgey, I also tried that, the DIV is the first element after the body tag, I even made the body relative. The Div is floating on top perfectly but it is not staying when the window re-sizes.

Comment: Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/DaNcp/  If it's not working for you, can you post an example or code?

Comment: CWolves, the example shows the positioned is fixed, the div needs to be on top. I am trying to paste the code in here, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

`position: fixed` is good.

http://jsfiddle.net/cDNr5/

Regards, Dennis